# How does G1 update pointers in young only collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

I understand that G1 keeps remembered sets to keep track of pointers pointing into a region. Then I guess that it holds a forwarding table for the region being evacuated to figure out the new addresses. But the G1 paper says that no remembered set processing is required for young only collections. I could not find any detailed explanation online. How does G1 update the references between young regions or inside a young region during evacuation?

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: This question is nowhere near being a discussion. There are not many implementation details either in papers or oracle documentations, making the source code only source of information. The guess about the forwarding tables is there because I know from experience it is used in some garbage collector implementatons, which the G1 paper does not give any details about its usage.

Comment: When you refer to statements made in a specific paper, you should include a link  to the paper.